# How to organize LDAP Groups and account?

Tags: ldap, openldap

As I konw, LDAP have four objectClass to represent the organization

1. groupOfUniqueNames
2. groupOfNames
3. organizationalUnit
4. posixGroup

And It have four objectClass to represent people

1. posixAccount
2. shadowAccount
3. organizationalPerson
4. inetOrgPerson

This is where I am confused. In general, which objectClass should be used to organize the relationship between departments and personnel? In My LDAP Server

Comment: You should elaborate on how you want to use the data. Which LDAP clients? Which use-cases?

Comment: You haven't provided much information, but it most likely won't matter which objectclass you choose. If you need to use specific attributes, look at the definition for each objectclass; you can see required attributes. The application is the important part. When you query LDAP for users, use whatever objectclass you chose. Same for groups.